# rows wise mapping of two files in shell or awk

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

File1

```
5063005905|06776|0|1

5063005905|06776|1|16

5063005905|06776|2|59729

4999999999|Z9991|2|119
```

File2

```
5063005905|Z9992|0|59730

5063005905|Z9992|1|16

4999999999|Z9991|2|121


4999999999|Z9991|2|122
```

Loop through File1 on column 1 and do look up in file2 based on column 1 and merge rows in one line. Here 5063005905 is 3 times in file1 but only 2 in file 2 so one will be null and other two should map.

Similarly 4999999999 is once in file1 but twice in file 2.

Output desired

```
5063005905|06776|0|1 : null

5063005905|06776|1|16 : 5063005905|Z9992|1|16

5063005905|06776|2|59729 : 5063005905|Z9992|0|59730

4999999999|Z9991|2|119 : 4999999999|Z9991|2|121

Null: 4999999999|Z9991|2|122
```

I used following

```
while read x
do

    ppt=`echo $x |cut -d'|' -f1`
    grep -w $ppt file2|while read -r line ;do
    echo "$x:$line" 
done<file1
```

Comment: Will these numbers always be in the same order in both files, are they always clustered, or is the order random?

Comment: Order will be random. We need to do look up.

Comment: File1 has 3 instances of 5063005905, whereas File2 only 2 instances.  How should the instances be mapped, or doesn't it matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is close to the desired output.  Put the following into a file like `awko` then `chmod +x awko`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS="|" }

# concatenate matching rows in the first file
/^[0-9]/ && NR==FNR { a[$1] = ($1 in a ? a[$1] ":" : "") $0; next }
# concatenate rows in reverse order in the 2nd file
/^[0-9]/ { b[$1] = $0 ($1 in b ? ":" b[$1] : "" ) }

END {
    # walk a array
    for( i in a ) {
        # split out the concatenated data
        a2_cnt = split( a[i], a2, ":" )
        b2_cnt = 0
        if( i in b ) b2_cnt = split( b[i], b2, ":" )

        # get a max() value for k
        k = (b2_cnt > a2_cnt) ? b2_cnt : a2_cnt

        # a2 goes up, b2 goes down to make the output
        for( j = 1; j < a1_cnt || k > 0; j++ ) {
            a2_val = j in a2 ? a2[j] : "null"
            b2_val = k in b2 ? b2[k] : "null"
            print a2_val " : " b2_val
            k--
        }
    }
}
```

Running `awko file1 file2` gives me the following output:

```
4999999999|Z9991|2|119 : 4999999999|Z9991|2|121
null : 4999999999|Z9991|2|122
5063005905|06776|0|1 : null
5063005905|06776|1|16 : 5063005905|Z9992|0|59730
5063005905|06776|2|59729 : 5063005905|Z9992|1|16
```

It appears that you want the data sorted by the 4th column before it's re-assembled.  In that case you can `sort -k4,4 -t"|" file1 > file1.sorted` ( similar for file2 ).

Running `awko file1.sorted file2.sorted` lines up the data as in your example, although the output is sorted differently:

```
4999999999|Z9991|2|119 : 4999999999|Z9991|2|121
null : 4999999999|Z9991|2|122
5063005905|06776|0|1 : null
5063005905|06776|1|16 : 5063005905|Z9992|1|16
5063005905|06776|2|59729 : 5063005905|Z9992|0|59730
```

The script could probably be simplified.  It was my first go at it.  To avoid the sort calls, a new array with a `$4` index could be build from `a2` or `b2` and then sorted and  with an `asorti()` call.  I've don't have the time now to play with that.